# Convert monthly cumulative values to current month values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the following data `df1` with missing January data, `cumul_val1` and `cumul_val2` are the monthly cumulative values of `value1` and `value2` respectively.

```
          date  cumul_val1  cumul_val2
0   2020-05-31    48702.97    45919.59
1   2020-06-30    69403.68    62780.21
2   2020-07-31    83631.36    75324.61
3   2020-08-31    98485.95    88454.14
4   2020-09-30   117072.67   103484.20
5   2020-10-31   133293.80   116555.76
6   2020-11-30   150834.45   129492.36
7   2020-12-31   176086.22   141442.95
8   2021-02-28    17363.14    13985.87
9   2021-03-31    36007.05    27575.82
10  2021-04-30    50305.00    40239.76
11  2021-05-31    66383.32    54318.08
12  2021-06-30    88635.35    72179.07
13  2021-07-31   101648.18    84895.41
14  2021-08-31   114192.81    98059.73
15  2021-09-30   130331.78   112568.07
16  2021-10-31   143040.71   124933.62
17  2021-11-30   158130.73   137313.96
18  2021-12-31   179433.41   147602.08
19  2022-02-28    15702.61    14499.38
20  2022-03-31    31045.96    27764.95
21  2022-04-30    39768.15    39154.31
22  2022-05-31    50738.38    52133.62
```

I now want to convert them into monthly values. For example, the value of `value1` on `2021-04-30` is calculated by `50305.00-36007.05`. It can be seen that the value in January is missing, so the current month value in February is the accumulated value itself, and the current month value in March will be the accumulated value in March minus the accumulated value in February.

May I ask how to achieve it?

The expected result:

```
          date  cumul_val1  cumul_val2  month_val1  month_val2
0   2020-05-31    48702.97    45919.59         NaN         NaN
1   2020-06-30    69403.68    62780.21    20700.71    16860.62
2   2020-07-31    83631.36    75324.61    14227.68    12544.40
3   2020-08-31    98485.95    88454.14    14854.59    13129.53
4   2020-09-30   117072.67   103484.20    18586.72    15030.06
5   2020-10-31   133293.80   116555.76    16221.13    13071.56
6   2020-11-30   150834.45   129492.36    17540.65    12936.60
7   2020-12-31   176086.22   141442.95    25251.77    11950.59
8   2021-02-28    17363.14    13985.87    17363.14    13985.87
9   2021-03-31    36007.05    27575.82    18643.91    13589.95
10  2021-04-30    50305.00    40239.76    14297.96    12663.94
11  2021-05-31    66383.32    54318.08    16078.32    14078.32
12  2021-06-30    88635.35    72179.07    22252.03    17860.99
13  2021-07-31   101648.18    84895.41    13012.83    12716.34
14  2021-08-31   114192.81    98059.73    12544.63    13164.32
15  2021-09-30   130331.78   112568.07    16138.97    14508.34
16  2021-10-31   143040.71   124933.62    12708.94    12365.55
17  2021-11-30   158130.73   137313.96    15090.02    12380.34
18  2021-12-31   179433.41   147602.08    21302.68    10288.12
19  2022-02-28    15702.61    14499.38    15702.61    14499.38
20  2022-03-31    31045.96    27764.95    15343.35    13265.57
21  2022-04-30    39768.15    39154.31     8722.19    11389.36
22  2022-05-31    50738.38    52133.62    10970.22    12979.31
```

**Notes:** in order to simplify the question, I added a new alternative sample data `df2` without missing months:

```
          date    cumul_val  monthly_val
0   2020-09-30  32144142.46          NaN
1   2020-10-31  36061223.45   3917080.99
2   2020-11-30  40354684.50   4293461.05
3   2020-12-31  44360036.58   4005352.08
4   2021-01-31   4130729.28   4130729.28
5   2021-02-28   7985781.64   3855052.36
6   2021-03-31  12306556.74   4320775.10
7   2021-04-30  16873032.10   4566475.36
8   2021-05-31  21730065.01   4857032.91
9   2021-06-30  26816787.85   5086722.84
10  2021-07-31  31785276.80   4968488.95
11  2021-08-31  37030178.38   5244901.58
12  2021-09-30  42879767.13   5849588.75
13  2021-10-31  48392250.79   5512483.66
14  2021-11-30  53655448.65   5263197.86
15  2021-12-31  59965790.04   6310341.39
16  2022-01-31   5226910.15   5226910.15
17  2022-02-28   9481147.06   4254236.91
18  2022-03-31  14205738.71   4724591.65
19  2022-04-30  19096746.32   4891007.61
20  2022-05-31  24033460.77   4936714.45
21  2022-06-30  28913566.31   4880105.54
22  2022-07-31  34099663.15   5186096.84
23  2022-08-31  39082926.81   4983263.66
24  2022-09-30  44406354.61   5323427.80
25  2022-10-31  48889431.89   4483077.28
26  2022-11-30  52956747.09   4067315.20
27  2022-12-31  57184652.60   4227905.51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had there been no gap in the data, the problem would have been an easy `.diff()`. However, since there are gaps, we need to fill those gap with 0, calculate the diff, then keep only the original months.

```py
idx = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
month_val = (
    df[["cumul_val1", "cumul_val2"]]
    # Fill the gap months with 0
    .set_index(idx)
    .reindex(pd.date_range(idx.min(), idx.max(), freq="M"), fill_value=0)
    # Take the diff
    .diff()
    # Keep only the original months
    .loc[idx]
    # Beat into shape for the subsequent concat
    .set_axis(["month_val1", "month_val2"], axis=1)
    .set_index(df.index)
)

result = pd.concat([df, month_val], axis=1)
```

---

Edit: the OP clarified that for the first entry of the year, be it Jan or Feb, the monthly value is the same as a cumulative value. In that case, use this:

```py
cumul_cols = ["cumul_val1", "cumul_val2"]
monthly_cols = [f"month_val{i+1}" for i in range(len(cumul_cols))]

# Make sure `date` is of type Timestamp and the dataframe is sorted. You data
# may have satisfied both conditions already.`
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = df.sort_values("date")

# Return True if current row is in the same year as the previous row.
# Repeat the result for each cumul_val column.
is_same_year = np.tile(
    df["date"].dt.year.diff().eq(0).to_numpy()[:, None],
    (1, len(cumul_cols)),
)

month_val = np.where(
    is_same_year,
    df[cumul_cols].diff(),
    df[cumul_cols],
)
month_val[0, :] = np.nan

df[monthly_cols] = month_val
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. I tested it using the original dataset `df1` of the question, and there is no problem; but if I use the dataset `df2` at the bottom of the question, it seems that incorrect results will be generated, can you please take a look?

Comment: Hm... the expected values in the second dataset don't follow the rules you described. Why does `monthly_val` reset every January?

Comment: The first value of each year, whether it is January or February, the cumulative value is the same as the current month value. To calculate the current month's value in January or February of the current year, we cannot use the accumulated value in December of the previous year.

Comment: For some economic data, January is missing and February values represent the combined value from January to February. Both situations exist in reality.

Comment: Aha... I coded it to a different requirement. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to use your date as a PeriodIndex with monthly frequencies:

```
# set up the date as a monthly period Index
df2 = df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')).set_index('date')

# subtract the previous month
df2.sub(df2.shift(freq='1M'), fill_value=0).reindex_like(df2)
```

Output:

```
         cumul_val1  cumul_val2
date                           
2020-05    48702.97    45919.59
2020-06    20700.71    16860.62
2020-07    14227.68    12544.40
2020-08    14854.59    13129.53
2020-09    18586.72    15030.06
2020-10    16221.13    13071.56
2020-11    17540.65    12936.60
2020-12    25251.77    11950.59
2021-02    17363.14    13985.87
2021-03    18643.91    13589.95
2021-04    14297.95    12663.94
2021-05    16078.32    14078.32
2021-06    22252.03    17860.99
2021-07    13012.83    12716.34
2021-08    12544.63    13164.32
2021-09    16138.97    14508.34
2021-10    12708.93    12365.55
2021-11    15090.02    12380.34
2021-12    21302.68    10288.12
2022-02    15702.61    14499.38
2022-03    15343.35    13265.57
2022-04     8722.19    11389.36
2022-05    10970.23    12979.31
```

If you want to assign back to the original DataFrame:

```
df[['month_val1', 'month_val2']] = df2.sub(df2.shift(freq='1M'), fill_value=0).reindex_like(df2).to_numpy()
```

Updated `df`:

```
          date  cumul_val1  cumul_val2  month_val1  month_val2
0   2020-05-31    48702.97    45919.59    48702.97    45919.59
1   2020-06-30    69403.68    62780.21    20700.71    16860.62
2   2020-07-31    83631.36    75324.61    14227.68    12544.40
3   2020-08-31    98485.95    88454.14    14854.59    13129.53
4   2020-09-30   117072.67   103484.20    18586.72    15030.06
5   2020-10-31   133293.80   116555.76    16221.13    13071.56
6   2020-11-30   150834.45   129492.36    17540.65    12936.60
7   2020-12-31   176086.22   141442.95    25251.77    11950.59
8   2021-02-28    17363.14    13985.87    17363.14    13985.87
9   2021-03-31    36007.05    27575.82    18643.91    13589.95
10  2021-04-30    50305.00    40239.76    14297.95    12663.94
11  2021-05-31    66383.32    54318.08    16078.32    14078.32
12  2021-06-30    88635.35    72179.07    22252.03    17860.99
13  2021-07-31   101648.18    84895.41    13012.83    12716.34
14  2021-08-31   114192.81    98059.73    12544.63    13164.32
15  2021-09-30   130331.78   112568.07    16138.97    14508.34
16  2021-10-31   143040.71   124933.62    12708.93    12365.55
17  2021-11-30   158130.73   137313.96    15090.02    12380.34
18  2021-12-31   179433.41   147602.08    21302.68    10288.12
19  2022-02-28    15702.61    14499.38    15702.61    14499.38
20  2022-03-31    31045.96    27764.95    15343.35    13265.57
21  2022-04-30    39768.15    39154.31     8722.19    11389.36
22  2022-05-31    50738.38    52133.62    10970.23    12979.31
```

Comment: Thanks! Please note `month_val1` and `month_val2` in `2020-05-31` should be `NaN`s,  and if we use `df2` at the bottom of the post, it seems that incorrect results will be generated, :)

Comment: But why? You fill `2021-02-28` even if there is no data before. Anyway, if you want to you can just assign NaN to the first row?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, as I explained to @Code Different: for some economic data, January is missing and February values represent the combined value from January to February. The first value of each year, whether it is January or February, the cumulative value is the same as the current month value. To calculate the current month's value in January or February of the current year, we cannot use the accumulated value in December of the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately pandas offers a diff function for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-05-31',48702.97,45919.59], ['2020-06-30',69403.68,62780.21], ['2020-07-31',83631.36,75324.61]], columns=['date','cumul_val1','cumul_val2'])
df['val1'] = df['cumul_val1'].diff()
df['val2'] = df['cumul_val2'].diff()
print(df)
```

Comment: Sorry, Pandas `diff()` will not differentiate between years.

Comment: NO. Diff just takes the difference between previous row. I just noticeed you begin accumulating from zero each year.

Comment: Ok I'll test it with the data I updated at the end of this question to see if I get the desired result.